# how to get directive attribute values while using submit button

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here i created sample program using angularJs  directive and controller, in directive i m created some attributes like (print-Display="true" is-Silent="false" is-Authentication="false" is-Download="false"), how to get this attribute values while using submit button (Controller)

Thanks in advance

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('telPrint', ['$http',
  function($http) {
    return {
      restrict: 'AEC',
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope: {
        ngModel: '=',
        printDisplay: '@',
        canShow: '@',
        isChecked: '@',
        isAuthentication: '@',
        isDownload: '@',

      },
      template: '<span  > <input type="checkbox"  name="ngModel"  ng-checked="checked">  <label > Print </label></span> ',
      controller: function($scope, $rootScope) {
        $scope.printOption = [];
        $scope.Authentication = $scope.isAuthentication;
        $scope.Silent = $scope.isSilent;
        $scope.Download = $scope.isDownload;

      },

      link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ngModelController) {
        var labelName = iAttrs.getString;
        var labelName = labelName.split(",");
        var language = labelName[0]; // Language EN or Fr
        var fieldlabelName = labelName[1]; // Label Name
        var fieldmoduleName = labelName[2]; // Module Name (global or local)




        if (iAttrs.isSilent == "true") {
          scope.checked = true;
        } else if (iAttrs.isSilent == "false") {
          scope.checked = false;
        }

        console.log(iAttrs.printDisplay)




      }
    };
  }
])


app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.printcontr = function() {
    console.log("Inside ")

  }



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="row col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <tel-Print ng-model="taxmaster.print" get-string="lbl,print,common" print-Display="true" is-Silent="true" is-Authentication="false" is-Download="true"></tel-Print>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" ng-click="printcontr()" />
      </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

By `scope.$parent`, you can access `$scope` of the controller:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('telPrint', ['$http',
  function($http) {
    return {
      restrict: 'AEC',
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope: {
        ngModel: '=',
        printDisplay: '@',
        canShow: '@',
        isChecked: '@',
        isAuthentication: '@',
        isDownload: '@',

      },
      template: '<span  > <input type="checkbox"  name="ngModel"  ng-checked="checked">  <label > Print </label></span> ',
      controller: function($scope, $rootScope) {
        $scope.printOption = [];
        $scope.Authentication = $scope.isAuthentication;
        $scope.Silent = $scope.isSilent;
        $scope.Download = $scope.isDownload;

      },

      link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ngModelController) {
        var labelName = iAttrs.getString;
        var labelName = labelName.split(",");
        var language = labelName[0]; // Language EN or Fr
        var fieldlabelName = labelName[1]; // Label Name
        var fieldmoduleName = labelName[2]; // Module Name (global or local)




        if (iAttrs.isSilent == "true") {
          scope.checked = true;
        } else if (iAttrs.isSilent == "false") {
          scope.checked = false;
        }

        console.log(iAttrs.printDisplay);


        // Set data
        scope.$parent.language = labelName[0];
        scope.$parent.fieldlabelName = labelName[1];
        scope.$parent.fieldmoduleName = labelName[2];

      }
    };
  }
])


app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.printcontr = function() {
    console.log("Inside ");

    //Retrive data
    console.info('language=', $scope.language);
    console.info('fieldlabelName=', $scope.fieldlabelName);
    console.info('fieldmoduleName=', $scope.fieldmoduleName);

  }



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="row col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <tel-Print ng-model="taxmaster.print" get-string="lbl,print,common" print-Display="true" is-Silent="true" is-Authentication="false" is-Download="true"></tel-Print>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" ng-click="printcontr()" />
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest if you have a need to fetch directive attributes inside parent controller then while defining directive's scope instead of using '@', use '=' (two way binding) so that whatever you will be changing any attribute in the directive, you will always have those values in the parent controller.

```
app.directive('telPrint', ['$http',
  function($http) {
    return {
      restrict: 'AEC',
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope: {
        ngModel: '=',
        printDisplay: '=',
        canShow: '=',
        isChecked: '=',
        isAuthentication: '=',
        isDownload: '=',

      }...
```